# Accessing a List or Dictionary using a Variable for the name

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```py
plants = {
    "rose" : [10, 20],
    "lily" : [30, 40]
}
rose = [11, 22]
lily = [33, 44]

...

    for name in plants.items():
        # Get this value from the List 'name'
        x = name[0]
    # Get this value from the dictionary 'plants' where key = 'name' 
        y = plants[name][0]
```

This is an overly-simplified version of my code.

I have a dictionary named `plants` that has some keys & values in it that I use in my program. The key also corresponds to the name of a list that has some values processed elsewhere in my program.

I want Python to do this (*PSEUDO-CODE*):

```py
    for name in plants.items():
        # Get this value from the List 'name'
        x = "rose"[0]
    # Get this value from the dictionary 'plants' where key = 'name' 
        y = plants["rose"][0]
```

And of course continue the iteration..

**EDIT**
To give a little more context, one of my functions is constantly updating the values in the plants dictionary. The values in the lists are accumulated calculations based on those values.

They need to be used for different functions in my program so I want to keep them separate.

Comment: I need something more dynamic. There are lots of entries in `plants` dictionary

Comment: something seems off, you want to grab values from the lists which have the variable name associated with each plant? that won't work because you can't dynamically call on a variable in the global namespace (well you can but it's bad practice, especially in the context shown here)

Comment: Variable names should not be treated like values. That's why we have dictionaries. If you need to do this you should make another dictionary with `rose` and `lily` as keys.

Comment: See updated post

Comment: what's `x` and `y` in your psuedocode, what is that trying to achieve or I should ask better what do you want out of the output from `x` and `y` ?

Comment: `rose` is a key in dictionary `plants`. It also has a corresponding list named `rose` that are accumulated calculations based on real-time facts that dictionary `plants` has. So for the first iteration, I need to get `x` from list `rose[0]` and `y` from `plants[rose][0]` so I can calculate `z = x + y`

Comment: If you can imagine how difficult to maintain this would be with 1000 variables, then you’ll understand why what you’re doing is wrong.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't understand though. I see two solutions: use if statements for every condition or do what I'm trying to do, which I know is possible in other languages? There are 20 keys in `plants`. I could create another dictionary to seperate real-time from accumulated, but I see myself ending at the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves modifying your dictionary but it might be as close as you get to what you want to do.

```
rose = [11, 22]
lily = [33, 44]
plants = {
    'rose' : [10, 20, rose],
    'lily' : [30, 40, lily]
    }
for key, value in plants.items () :
    print (key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is an adequate solution to the issue described above. I had a brain fart last night... I would be able to do what I wanted to if I just used two dictionaries as someone suggested in the comments of the original issue. For anyone landing here in the future from Google, you cannot use the variable as a "literal string" value, i.e. `name[0]`, but `otherDict[name][0]` works fine.